# JS: new Date() is not accepting date string in my own locale (d/m/y)

Tags: javascript, locale, date

My browser (ie. my OS) should know I'm in Australia and what the correct date format is. In this case, d/m/y, not m/d/y. However if I run the following code:

```
alert(new Date("21/11/1968"))
```

The result is "Thu Sep 11 1969". It is thinking the month comes first and adjusting accordingly.

Why is this? Is the answer to always use a universal format as input to date functions, or is there a way to tell the browser to expect dates input in my locale format?

Comment: See this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539346/manipulating-dates-in-javascript-without-the-date-object)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Date object is very weak. You **cannot** tell it what format to expect. You can create it with a string in m/d/y like you stated, or `new Date(year, month, day[, hours, seconds, milliseconds]);`

Comment: You can also get libraries like http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/ to get a more powerful date function.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I needed to be told that. :)
@Ktash, I've ended up using that library, thanks very much.

Answer (score 20):

It's pretty simple to convert your date string to a format that will give the expected result ('yyyy/mm/dd' or 'yyyy-mm-dd'):

```
new Date("21/11/1968".split('/').reverse().join('/'));
```

[**Edit 2023**] You may like this more generic method (play with it @[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hgfmem?file=index.js)).

```js
document.querySelector("#result").textContent = `
  DateFromString("2017/03/22", "ymd")\n    => ${
    DateFromString("2017/03/22", "ymd")}
  DateFromString("03/22/2017", "mdy")\n    => ${
    DateFromString("03/22/2017", "mdy")}
  DateFromString("22-03-2017", "dmy")\n    => ${
    DateFromString("22-03-2017 22:22:12", "dmy")}`;

function DateFromString(dateString, format = "ymd") {
  const canNot = `"${
    dateString ?? `[no string given]`}" can not be converted to Date`;
  const ds2Array = ds => ds.split(/[T :\-\/.,]/g)
    .filter(v => !!(v.trim()));
  
  return !dateString ? canNot : canDo();

  function canDo() {
    const mapFormat = [...format].reduce((a, b, i) => (a[b] = i, a), {});
    const dateStr2Array = ds2Array(dateString);
    const datePart = dateStr2Array.slice(0, 3);
    const timePart = dateStr2Array.slice(3);
    let [year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds] = 
      [ +datePart[mapFormat.y],
        +datePart[mapFormat.m] - 1, 
        +datePart[mapFormat.d], ]
      .concat([...Array(4)].map( (_, i) => +timePart[i] || 0 ) );

    return [year, month, date].filter(u => isNaN(u)).length
      ? canNot 
      : new Date( year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds );
  }
}
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: That's a bit of a hack, not a universally applicable solution. I'm looking for a method that can be used consistently in all circumstances, based on how the Date object works.

Comment: this solves the date format, but for me the date () function returned true for the date 30/02/2014 and that date does not exist, it is good to check.

Comment: @vandersondf: that's how the Date constructor works. Dixit MDN: `Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, if values are greater than their logical range (e.g. 13 is provided as the month value or 70 for the minute value), the adjacent value will be adjusted`. So 30/02/2014 becomes 02/03/214. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 9):

new Date(string_date) supports the following Date formats:

1. MM-dd-yyyy
2. yyyy/MM/dd
3. MM/dd/yyyy
4. MMMM dd, yyyy
5. MMM dd, yyyy

Comment: actually, it doesn't; any format other than ISO is explicitly stated as implementation-dependent and not really portable across browsers (see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse with full doc of the caveats , which is what the string c-tor internally calls) - see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781887/javascript-date-parse-with-specific-locale

Answer (score -1):

You need to parse it using a new date object like

`const myDate = new Date('Wed Dec 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)')`

Then convert it:

`const dateFormatted = myDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US")`