# Javascript Issue converting string to date

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

I am unable to convert strings to dates correctly in my environment.  My string is in English Australian format dd/mm/yyyy, but when I convert to date I assume it is taking on a different format?

```
var dateString = "27/10/2015"
var testdate = new Date(dateString);
```

testdate will now have a value of:

**Fri Mar 10 2017 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)**

Can anyone Please help!!!!

Comment: Try to add your timezone while doing conversion

Comment: Similar discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165483/js-new-date-is-not-accepting-date-string-in-my-own-locale-d-m-y

Comment: If you have in future more dates to convert from strings I highly recommend using momentjs library.

Comment: Thanks visibleman.  The link got me the answer. I am now using date.js

Answer (score 1):

Date() doesn't support the format that you use **day/month/year**, so you get wrong result, you can use it with this string **m/d/y** or **split your date string like so** :

```
var tmp = "15/02/2016".split('/');//you get ["15","02","2016"]
var testdate = new Date(tmp[2],tmp[1]-1,tmp[0]);//months are zero based array ,so we subtract -1
console.log(testdate);//Mon Feb 15 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)
```

Hope helps, good luck.

Comment: this one is simple and clear, works great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the javascript function for getting day, month & year.

```
today = new Date();
dd = today.getDate();
mm = today.getMonth();
yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd; }
  if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm; }

  today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy
```

This will return formatted date like **"27/10/2015"**

Comment: Op is asking for string to date conversion, this seems to be the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple regex replace before creating the date object. The day & month ordering is messed up in JS. There is no way to use your own custom format to match any date string.

`var testdate = new Date(dateString.replace(/(\d*)\/(\d*)(.*)/, "$2/$1$3"));`

Comment: There's no reason to expect a browser to support m/d/y either other than most browsers do. There is no specification that requires them to support it, and various browsers support it differently  (e.g. in regard to out of bounds values).

Answer (score 0):

Parsing of date strings is almost entirely implementation dependent. Support for a limited number of ISO 8601 formats is specified in [*ECMAScript 2015*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format), however not all browsers in use support them.

Most browsers support a number of formats, including m/d/y, but there is no specification that requires them to, so it should not be expected that they will.

You are much better off to manually parse strings. A library can help, but is rarely necessary. To parse a date in the format d/m/y as a local date (i.e. where the system timezone offset is considered) and validate the parts, consider:

```js
/*  Parse date string in d/m/y format as a local date
**
**  @param {string} s - string to parse
**  @returns {Date} - if any date value is out of bounds, returns a
**                    Date with time value of NaN (per ECMAScript 2015)
*/
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

document.write(parseDMY('27/10/2015'));
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve my issue I followed the link provided by visibleman in the comment of my og question.
I am now using date.js library.  I had tried this in the past but was unaware of the culture info setting:
[getting started with date.js](http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/)

I now use 2 seperate files and allow the user to nominate what format they want the date in.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
//current format is dd/mm/yy
var dateString = "27/10/2015" ; 

//change the format to mm/dd/yy
var dateString = "10/27/2015" ; 

       // then use
var testdate = new Date(dateString);
```

Comment: Parsing of strings other than the format specified in ECMAScript 2015 is entirely implementation dependent and therefore should not be relied on. For example, given `new Date('31/2/2015')` most browsers will return 'Invalid date', however Firefox returns a date for 2 July, 2017.